# How to round down a double to the nearest smaller int in C?

Tags: c, integer, double, rounding

I've got a `double`:

```
double d = 25.342;
```

How can I convert it to `25`?

If it were `-12.46` I'd like to get `-13`.

Comment: I'd like the result to be of type int

Comment: For the record, what you're asking for is rounding, not casting.

Comment: @Jon No this is not `rounding`. Rounding is transforming the number to the "nearest" integer.

Comment: It absolutely is rounding.  Round-to-nearest is one *type* of rounding.  Round-down is another.

Comment: I don't have the ability to do so, but this question should really be retitled.  It has nothing to do with typecasts except insofar as he wants the result in an integer.

Comment: Question: What if floor(14.6) returns 13.99999?

Comment: aib:  Floating-point representations are good about representing integers (as long as there's enough digits).  I'd be real surprised to have a problem with floor().

Comment: ... and if you encounter a system on which `floor( )` returns a non-integral value, that's a bug, and you should complain to whoever is providing the math library on that system.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
int i = (int)floor(25.342);
```

Comment: I'd like the result to be of type int

Comment: The problems start when the argument to floor is > INT_MAX or < INT_MIN.

Comment: In that case, you can't actually get an integer version of the floor of the value, so it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @KevinKostlan `(int)floor(-25.342)` returns -26, while `(int) -25.342` returns -25. `floor` is not necessary if you know the value is positive.

Comment: In that case, you could do this without the C library as follows, correct?
`int i = (dbl >= 0 ? (int) dbl : ((int) dbl) -1;`
@amarillo

Comment: @Aaron Campbell `((int) dbl) -1` does not work when `dbl` is a negative whole number.

Answer (score 16):

```
int i = (int)floor(25.342);
```

Note this will convert 12.99999 to 12.

[Ref](https://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/math.h/floor.php)

Comment: Upvoted for reference link, but you don't need the cast to the int there, floor already returns as an int?

Comment: `floor( )` returns a double (§7.12.9.2 in the C standard).

Answer (score 1):

Where `x` is your `25.342`:

```
int i = x >= 0 ? (int)(x+0.5) : (int)(x-0.5)
```

Comment: @Mike I don't think he wants to round numbers. Look at the negative number example :)

Comment: I did, his post said "( If it were -12.46 I'd like to get -13)" So I presumed a little rounding.

Comment: That's rounding to lower, or, essentially, floor().

Comment: Wouldn't rounding -12.46 give you and integer value of -12 and not -13?

Comment: Not with the check for negativity.

Comment: Rounding -12.46 to closest integer will produce -12, as will rounding closer to zero.  Rounding to lower will give you -13, and this is what the questioner wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    double d = 25.342;
    double e = -12.99;

    printf("%d\n",(int)round(d)); // 25
    printf("%d\n",(int)round(e)); // -13

    return 0;
}
```

You may also want to take a look at stdint.h

Comment: Fails for many values like `25.9` as it does not "round down a double to the nearest smaller int".